# get last inserted record's primary key using LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I can get the primary key of last inserted raw using LAST_INSERT_ID() function.but I want to know when two pcs insert a record at same time what happened to result of above function?is there any possibilty to give an wrong result?it means one pc insert a record and before get the id 2nd pc insert a record at same time,and above function will gives 2nd records id?is it happen?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks even the most basic research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could find your answer in this statement from the [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

No, the id returned to your connection is just yours

Comment: Shh, don't tell them there's a manual. Now everyone'll want one.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID function returns the first AUTO_INCREMENT value that was set by the most recent INSERT or UPDATE statement that affected an AUTO_INCREMENT column.